# Search through a text file in between to specified characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, search

I want to search a specified section of the attached text file based on the '#' character. Basically, I want to look at all the data starting at a found '#' and end at a line with '#'. In these sections, I'd also like to look for a specified string. I am coding in python.

**TEXT FILE (The bolded events have a '#' symbol in front of the number ex: the real file reads '#1 Women 1000 Yd Free')**

```
FAST - CA

HY-TEK's MEET MANAGER 7.0 - 11:32 PM 2/11/2018 Page 1
2018 Presidents' Day Senior Swimming Classic
Psych Sheet

#1 Women 1000 Yd Free
10:39.39 SECT
Name

Age

Team

1 Zamora Gallegos, Mariana
15 BC
2 Arzave, Juli

16

SBA-SI

Seed Time
1:00.21 SECT
10:02.58 SECT

3 Aguilar Ortega, Martha
18 Ruth
BC

10:05.72 SECT

4 Nowaski, Danielle 17

10:13.74 SECT

CAST-SI

5 Miranda Aguilar, Danitza
17 BC

10:23.30 SECT

6 Moreno Osuna, Ashely
16 Dariela
BC

10:23.70 SECT

7 Motekaitis, Mia

17

UCD-SN

10:24.96 SECT

8 Gardner, Amber

15

CROW-PC

10:27.86 SECT

9 Urias Quijas, Sophie14
AprilBC

53 Macias Ruiz, Alejandra
17 BC

11:23.81

45 Suehiro, Alex

54 Fuller, Monica

SMSC-CA

11:29.23

14 BC
46 Gallegos Portugal, Hanson

10:26.01

MP-PC

11:30.00

47 O'Connell, Daniel 17

CROW-PC

10:27.13

13 BC
56 Mendoza Camilo, Arely

11:30.58

48 Monge, Colin

PS-SI

10:27.63

57 DePaco, Lexi

15

CROW-PC

11:31.13

17 BC
49 Mejia Matamoros, Miguel

10:28.50

58 Morgan, Chloe

12

MRA-SI

11:57.36

50 Cebreros Gracia, Jorge
16

BC

10:30.06

59 Ferguson, Lizzie

18

MP-PC

12:12.40

51 Simpson, Aidan

ICAC-SI

10:30.20

60 Vera, Daniela

19

BERIM

52 Cordova Medina, Ivar
17

BC

10:30.57

53 Rascon, Esteban

SBA-SI

10:33.35

54 Mota Ezpinoza, Leonel
13

BC

10:34.09

55 Marsalek, Asa

16

SMSC-CA

10:34.14

56 Shitole, Viraj

17

DACA-PC

10:39.53

57 Friedrich, Aaron

15

SMSC-CA

10:40.67

58 Sokalzuk, Samuel 14

MP-PC

10:40.89

59 Jin, Lei

ICAC-SI

10:56.89

14

55 Duro, Dominique 18

9:12.23L SECT

#2 Men 1000 Yd Free
```

Comment: Format your text file as code.

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Any research? SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0):

Begin by using either the `string.find("#")`. It will return -1 if the hashtag doesn't exist. Once you find it, make an outer loop that iterates until you find the next hashtag. If you do find a hashtag, search the next 4-5 elements. For example, search if it says "women" or "men", contains a number for the distance. For example, for the distance, the isDigit method is perfect.

Inside that loop, check with your list of names and confirm when you have a match. For example, try using the == to check if the name matches. Once you do find the name, check the next 4 pieces of information and copy those down as a string.

Given about 30 names, and a list of about 3000 swimmers, it makes close to 100,000 comparisons meaning it could take a long time to run the program.

```
Outer loop (checks or #)
  if(#) --> check event, gender, etc.., and reset the global variable to the event so that the swimmers can be saved to it
  else --> do name comparisons
```